# AngularJS Dependent dropdown with ng-repeat is leaving blank

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a dependent dropdown but somehow the second dropdown is always leaving a blank if i am changing the first dropdown.

```
<select class="form-control DB_Control" id="Sector" ng-model="selected_sector" ng-init="selected_sector = initial_selected_sector"  ng-options="each.sector for each in data track by each.sector" ng-change="getSubsector()">

<select class="form-control DB_Control" ng-model='related_subsector3' ng-options="subsector for subsector in sub_sectors track by subsector" >

$scope.getSubsector = function() {
    $scope.related_subsector3 = $scope.sub_sectors[0]
}
```

Just for more information, if i am printing the value of $scope.related_subsector3 in function getSubsector, its printing correct value but its not setting the value in template.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would work. What I would try is to create another function called "$scope.getSubSectorChildren()" which would populate the second dropdown on the change of the first one. That way you can keep the data population more flexible and it would be easier to test/debug.